# AVAudioEngine stops running when changing input to AirPods

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I have trouble understanding AVAudioEngine's behaviour when switching audio input sources.

### Expected Behaviour

When switching input sources, AVAudioEngine's `inputNode` should adopt the new input source seamlessly.

### Actual Behaviour

When switching from AirPods to the iPhone speaker, AVAudioEngine stops working. No audio is routed through anymore. Querying `engine.isRunning` still returns true.

When subsequently switching back to AirPods, it still isn't working, but now `engine.isRunning` returns false.

Stopping and starting the engine on a route change does not help. Neither does calling `reset()`. Disconnecting and reconnecting the input node does not help, either. The only thing that reliably helps is discarding the whole engine and creating a new one.

### OS

This is on iOS 14, beta 5. I can't test this on previous versions I'm afraid; I only have one device around.

### Code to Reproduce

Here is a minimum code example. Create a simple app project in Xcode (doesn't matter whether you choose SwiftUI or Storyboard), and give it permissions to access the microphone in `Info.plist`. Create the following file `Conductor.swift`:

```swift
import AVFoundation

class Conductor {
    static let shared: Conductor = Conductor()
    
    private let _engine = AVAudioEngine?
    
    init() {
        // Session
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try? session.setActive(false)
        try! session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.defaultToSpeaker,
                                                           .allowBluetooth,
                                                           .allowAirPlay])
        try! session.setActive(true)

        _engine.connect(_engine.inputNode, to: _engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)
        _engine.prepare()
    }

    func start() { _engine.start() }
}
```

And in `AppDelegate`, call:

```swift
Conductor.shared.start()
```

This example will route the input straight to the output. If you don't have headphones, it will trigger a feedback loop.

### Question

What am I missing here? Is this expected behaviour? If so, it does not seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: It's been two year, but did you manage to solve this in the end?